# Low GPU Utilization by TensorFlow on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, gpu

I'm trying to get Neural Fictitious Self-Play algorithm to work on my domain in OpenSpiel. For now I have resorted to running the example provided in OpenSpiel which uses the algorithm on the domain of Kuhn Poker available [here](https://github.com/deepmind/open_spiel/blob/master/open_spiel/python/examples/kuhn_nfsp.py). The algorithm is supposed to learn an approximate optimal strategy in the game using several neural networks.

In order to achieve faster training I tried to get the program to run on my GPU - NVIDIA GeForce 1070 Ti 8G. I installed on native Ubuntu 20.04 following software: NVIDIA Driver Version 470.161.03, CUDA 11.2, cuDNN 8.1, and TensorFlow 2.11 (since these are the versions listed as compatible on the TensorFlow [webpage](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)), however, the runtime stayed the same.

My question is whether it is possible that TensorFlow (TF) is not running on my GPU, or whether the part of the code which is executed by TF and my GPU isn't as demanding in terms of computation as the rest of the application, and therefore the speed up isn't really visible. I'm also interested in any fixes which could decrease the time the neural networks take to train.

The TF code snippet listing available GPU devices to TF shows my GPU:
[TF GPU list snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rzl3.png)

Executing the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)
```

Yields following logs:

```
a: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2023-03-01 15:52:52.799632: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] a: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
b: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2023-03-01 15:52:52.799701: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] b: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2023-03-01 15:52:52.799744: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
product_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2023-03-01 15:52:52.799781: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] product_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2023-03-01 15:52:52.802271: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:1445] Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

nvcc output:
[nvcc output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxmsq.png)

nvidia-smi output, when the application isn't running:
[nvidia-smi without app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIOvY.png)

Notice that GPU-Util is at 0. When I've tried running it multiple times it didn't go above 3%.

When I execute the Kuhn Poker example I get the following TF logs:

```
2023-03-01 15:22:55.284702: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-03-01 15:22:55.843201: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/cechdav5/lib/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64:/home/cechdav5/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/
2023-03-01 15:22:55.843271: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/cechdav5/lib/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64:/home/cechdav5/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/
2023-03-01 15:22:55.843279: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/cechdav5/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:107: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
2023-03-01 15:22:56.368948: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:56.379909: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:56.380393: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I0301 15:22:56.381133 140353186489536 rl_environment.py:180] Using game settings: {'players': 2}
2023-03-01 15:22:56.386056: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-03-01 15:22:56.386967: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:56.387368: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:56.387748: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:57.582149: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:57.583162: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:57.583662: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2023-03-01 15:22:57.584301: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1613] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6926 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2023-03-01 15:22:57.909708: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:357] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
2023-03-01 15:22:58.898945: W tensorflow/c/c_api.cc:291] Operation '{name:'mlp_4/bias_10/Assign' id:1663 op device:{requested: '', assigned: ''} def:{{{node mlp_4/bias_10/Assign}} = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@mlp_4/bias_10"], _has_manual_control_dependencies=true, use_locking=true, validate_shape=true](mlp_4/bias_10, mlp_4/zeros_10)}}' was changed by setting attribute after it was run by a session. This mutation will have no effect, and will trigger an error in the future. Either don't modify nodes after running them or create a new session.
```

There are some info level logs and warnings, but none of it seems to indicate any real problems with the code execution. I couldn't really find fixes to these messages online either, with the exception of muting them which I didn't really find useful.

Lastly, the nvidia-smi output when the app is running in the background:
[nvidia-smi with app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeGHP.png)

The python3 app is the running example which reserves most of the GPU memory which I've read is the correct TensorFlow behavior, however, the GPU-Util stays at around 10% (5-15% is the range I have sampled). There seems to be slight increase in the GPU-Util when the app is running which might indicate that TF is executing the training of NNs on the GPU. I should note that this is the result I've gotten when I significantly increased the number of hidden layers of the NNs used in the app, and also batch size. Without these changes GPU-Util stayed even lower.

This is my third attempt, I've tried more or less the same setup with more recent Nvidia drivers, CUDA toolkit, and on Ubuntu 22.04, but it yielded the same results. I would appreciate any thoughts on what the problem causing slow runtime might be, and any tips on how to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like reasonable behaviour to me. Your application is using an extremely simple network (MLP with 1 layer of size 128). You probably spend a lot of time moving data to the GPU compared to the gains in speed you get for using it. Your bottleneck is your input pipeline.

Comment: Yes, for GPUs to be helpful, your code must be bottleneck by compute which can be parallelized, and is much more than the overhead of CPU-GPU transfers. GPUs are not magical silver bullets that always improve performance.